# Dropdown list in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that wanna to select category and tag from drop down list and bind it to a post , this is my ViewModel:

```
public class PostViewModel
    {
        public IList<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public IList<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my get action :

```
  public ActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(_categoryRepository.GetAllCategory());
            ViewBag.TagList = new SelectList(_tagRepository.GetAllTag());
            return View();
        }
```

now how can I get the Id dropdownlst to send it to the Post action?? :

```
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(post => post.Category)
        @Html.DropDownListFor   ????
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Category)
    </div>
```

I tried this one it it didn't work

```
<div>
            @Html.LabelFor(post => post.Category)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(post => post.Category, ViewBag.CategoryList as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Category)
        </div>
```

please give me a solution about this ,thanks

Comment: I Edited and added what I tried, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to avoid dynamic stuff like ViewBag and ViewData.** Use strongly typed views.

ViewModel is just a POCO class which we will use to transfer data between your view and the action method. It will be specific to the view.

You have a viewmodel but you are not using it properly. Add 2 more properties to your viewmodel for getting the selected item from the dropdown. Also i changed the name of your proprties to pluralized for (`Categories` ,`Tags`) because they are for storing a collection.

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Tags { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCategory { set;get;}
    public int SelectedTag { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your `GET` Action method, create an object of your view model and set the collection properties and then send that object to your view using `View` method.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var vm=new PostViewModel();
    vm.Categories= GetAllCategories();
    vm.Tags= GetAllTags();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetAllCategories` and `GetAllTags` are 2 methods which returns a collection of `SelectListItem` for categories and tags.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetAllCategories()
{
  List<SelectListItem> categoryList=new List<SelectListItem>();
  categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sample", Value = "1" });
  // TO DO : Read from your dB and fill here instead of hardcoding

  return categoryList;
}
```

and in your view,

```
@model PostViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategory, 
                       new SelectList(Model.Categories,"Value","Text"), "Select")

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTag, 
                       new SelectList(Model.Tags,"Value","Text"), "Select")


  <input type="submit" value="save" />


}
```

And in your HttpPost action method, you can get the selected items in the 2 properties we added

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(PostViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //check model.SelectedCategory and model.SelectedTag
     //save and redirect
  }
  //to do :reload the dropdown again.
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: thanks , I tried this, but got this error : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items  !! what is the Name you added above ?? name of category or what ??

Comment: Where are you getting the error ? Are you following my updated answer ? I updated your view model to have `SelectListItem` collections.

Comment: @EricNielsen: There was a typo. I was using the old property names in the GET action method. Corrected now. This should work fine.

Comment: yeah I tried your updated answer , you added GetAllCategories() , what is that !? How can I use it ???

Comment: @EricNielsen: `GetAllCategories` is a method which returns a collection of `SelectListItem` element for your categoeies from db. Here is a working sample app https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9ABE38A81F442D6!581&authkey=!AJMAJcA1mg9MHsA

Comment: I got that sample , sorry could you please write the line of code to how get the list of category and tag where you wrote // TO DO : Read from your dB and fill here instead of hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

you were close:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } // <-- Altered
    public int TagId { get; set; } // <-- Altered
}

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(post => post.Category)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(post => post.CategoryId, 
                                  ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                                  "--- Select Category ---")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(post => post.Category)
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ,but I got this error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryId '. how can I fix that ??

Comment: You should be referencing `ViewBag.CategoryList` not CategoryId